# How do I link and update a .png file in iWork Pages

Tags: pages

I have inserted a .png image into my pages document.  Is it possible for this image to refresh itself if the original file changes?

Comment: Sorry, images are imported (copied) to iWork documents, so they don't use the original file.

Comment: I thought that was the case, but thanks for confirming.